# Android char java.lang.String.charAt(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I'm trying to get the first char from a string in an Array-adapter.  After I run the application, it will work but while scrolling, the `listview` is crashing the application and I am getting the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char java.lang.String.charAt(int)' on a null object reference at this line  char first = typenameRGN.charAt(0);

Here is my code in ArrayAdapter:

```
String typenameRGN = all_Post.getStrShortName();
Log.e("typenameRGN ", " = " + typenameRGN);    

char first = typenameRGN.charAt(0);
Log.e("first ", " " + first);

String strTypeRGN = Character.toString(first);
Log.e("strTypeRGN ", " " + strTypeRGN);

holder.txtInitialLetter.setText(strTypeRGN);
```

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like all_Post.getStrShortName() is returning null. You might want to do a (typenameRGN != null) check. But look back at your data source and figure out why it's coming back null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let check arrayadapter all_Post .
Maybe this array altered(clear,..) when listview scroll and it return null